# mysql trigger after update multiple another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 tables

"description_acc_all_lang" -  this contains translations of text in 15 languages each field is the language translation

```
CREATE TABLE `description_acc_all_langs` (<br>
  `code` varchar(4) NOT NULL,(<br>
  `en_desc` varchar(256) NOT NULL,<br>
  `fr_desc` varchar(256) NOT NULL,<br>
  `es_desc` varchar(256) NOT NULL,<br>
  `pt_desc` varchar(256) NOT NULL,<br>
  `da_desc` varchar(256) NOT NULL,<br>
  `de_desc` varchar(256) NOT NULL,<br>
  `nl_desc` varchar(256) NOT NULL,<br>
  `no_desc` varchar(256) NOT NULL,<br>
  `sv_desc` varchar(256) NOT NULL,<br>
  `fi_desc` varchar(256) NOT NULL,<br>
  `pl_desc` varchar(256) NOT NULL,<br>
  `it_desc` varchar(256) NOT NULL,<br>
  `ru_desc` varchar(256) NOT NULL,<br>
  `cs_desc` varchar(256) NOT NULL,<br>
  `hu_desc` varchar(256) NOT NULL,<br>
  PRIMARY KEY  (`code`)<br>
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

A single record from this table

```
+------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+<br>
| code | en_desc                             | fr_desc | es_desc | pt_desc | da_desc | de_desc | nl_desc | no_desc | sv_desc | fi_desc | pl_desc | it_desc | ru_desc | cs_desc | hu_desc |<br>
+------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+<br>
| hs   | 30 minutes drive to big supermarket |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |<br>
+------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

code  - is the up to 4 letter unique code
en_desc  - is the English text
fr_desc  - is the French text
es_desc  - is the Spanish text
.._desc  - is the ....... text
etc

The 2nd table contains multiple records - one for each of the 15 language descriptions

```
code - 4 letter code this is <br>
desc - Text string - this needs to be updated from the xx_desc field in the "description_acc_all_langs" table lang - 2 letter country code.



CREATE TABLE `description_acc` (<br>
  `acc_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,<br>
  `code` varchar(10) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,<br>
  `desc` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,<br>
  `lang` varchar(2) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,<br>
  PRIMARY KEY  (`acc_id`),<br>
  UNIQUE KEY `codelang` (`code`,`lang`)<br>
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=211 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Extract from table showing all records for code "hs" in all languages

```
+--------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
| acc_id | code | desc                                                                  | lang |<br>
+--------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+<br>
|     25 | hs   | 30 minut jÃ­zdy do velkÃ½ch supermarketÅ¯                             | cs   |<br>
|     18 | hs   | 30 minutters kÃ¸rsel til stort supermarked                            | da   |<br>
|     26 | hs   | 30 Minuten Fahrt zum Supermarkt                                       | de   |<br>
|     14 | hs   | 30 minutes drive to big supermarket                                   | en   |<br>
|     28 | hs   | 30 minutos en coche de grandes supermercados                          | es   |<br>
|     21 | hs   | 30 minuutin ajomatkan suuri supermarket                               | fi   |<br>
|     27 | hs   | 30 minutes en voiture au grand supermarchÃ©                           | fr   |<br>
|     23 | hs   | 30 perc autÃ³Ãºtra a nagy szupermarket                                | hu   |<br>
|     17 | hs   | 30 minuti di auto a grande supermercato                               | it   |<br>
|     15 | hs   | 30 minuten rijden naar grote supermarkt                               | nl   |<br>
|     19 | hs   | 30 minutters kjÃ¸retur til store supermarked                          | no   |<br>
|     24 | hs   | 30 minut jazdy na duÅ¼y supermarket                                   | pl   |<br>
|     16 | hs   | 30 minutos de carro de um supermercado grande                         | pt   |<br>
|     22 | hs   | 30 Ð¼Ð¸Ð½ÑÑ ÐµÐ·Ð´Ñ Ð´Ð¾ Ð±Ð¾Ð»ÑÑÐ¾Ð³Ð¾ ÑÑÐ¿ÐµÑÐ¼Ð°ÑÐºÐµÑÐ°           | ru   |<br>
|     20 | hs   | 30 minuters bilfÃ¤rd till stora snabbkÃ¶p                             | sv   |<br>
+--------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+<br>
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)<br>
```

My trigger needs to update the record in each of the "area_description_acc" language records if a single field is updated in "area_description_acc_all_langs"

So in effect "area_description_acc_all_langs" contains all the translations and 1 code identifier in a single record, the "area_description_acc" contains 15 individual records for each of the 15 languages per code with a field "code" to identify it and a language identifier field "lang"

I started to try and understand how triggers are constructed but am just tying myself in knots

```
delimiter //
Create trigger update_all_recs
after update on description_acc_all_langs
for each row
begin
  update area_description_acc
  set desc = new.en_desc
  where members_house_area_description_acc_all_langs.code=members_house_area_description_acc.code;
    end//

delimiter ;
```

Any help on how to contruct the trigger would help me understand, I have chopped up many examples but after 2 days and too much coffee I think I need guidance and maybe some therapy.
Regards.

Comment: What is `members_house_area_description_acc_all_langs` that you mention in your trigger in `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_update_all_recs
AFTER UPDATE ON description_acc_all_langs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE description_acc
       SET `desc` = NEW.en_desc
     WHERE code = NEW.code AND lang = 'en';
    UPDATE description_acc
       SET `desc` = NEW.fr_desc
     WHERE code = NEW.code AND lang = 'fr';
    UPDATE description_acc
       SET `desc` = NEW.es_desc
     WHERE code = NEW.code AND lang = 'es';
    UPDATE description_acc
       SET `desc` = NEW.pt_desc
     WHERE code = NEW.code AND lang = 'pt';
   -- continue for all other languages
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: peterm - Perfect solution - I now understand the NEW.xxxx functionality. Many thanks Regards Martyn